# Will / in robots.txt also apply to the root directory?

Tags: robots.txt

In website.com/path/ there is a robots.txt file, that contains the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

I do NOT want it to apply for website.com, but only to the path itself.

The question is: does / actually mean ./ or does it refer to the web root folder?

The reasoninng: I don't want to give the list of folders in the robots.txt, but if a crawler gets to a private from some external link, it should not index it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly enough, it will also apply to the root folder.

Actually, every robots.txt applies first of all to the root folder, and only then you can give details regardding specific folders.

From [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html):

> When a robot looks for the "/robots.txt" file for URL, it strips the path component from the URL (everything from the first single slash), and puts "/robots.txt" in its place.
>
> For example, for "http://www.example.com/shop/index.html, it will remove the "/shop/index.html", and replace it with "/robots.txt", and will end up with "http://www.example.com/robots.txt".

Answer (score 3):

Your robots.txt MUST be placed in the host root, you can't have a robots.txt in `example.com/path/robots.txt`.

So you have to move your robots.txt one level up, to `example.com/robots.txt`. And now it's clear that `Disallow: /` blocks everything on this host.

If you don't want to give information about your "private" URLs, you could specify only the beginning of those URLs (if possible in your case):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /p
```

This would block all URLs that *start with* `example.com/p`, like:

- `example.com/p`
- `example.com/p.html`
- `example.com/path`
- `example.com/path/`
- `example.com/path/foobar`
- `example.com/p12asokd1`

If this is not possible (e.g. if your public URLs might start with such characters, too), you could use the `robots` `meta` element instead.

Note that when using `robots.txt` to block URLs, search engines might still index your URLs and link to it in their search results (e.g. when someone links to your private URLs). So these URLs aren't so "private" anymore. When using the `meta` way, (polite) search engines won't even index the URL, so that would be an advantage for you.

Comment: Thank you Unor, but this is exactly what I was trying to avoid: setting an exception list. What I found out is that there is no way to achieve what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @bizna: Is it not possible to find a beginning of the folder name that a) doesn’t give enough information to guess the full name and b) doesn’t conflict with other public folders?

Comment: Sadly enough, unor, this will not do. Folders are being created all the time, and it is a dynamic environment. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You might try `Disallow: /*/`, which will block anything that has a path and a slash. That will block `/foo/bar.html`, but it won't block `/index.html` in the root.

Unfortunately, it won't block `/foo`, although depending on your web server, requests for `/foo` might be redirected to `/foo/`, which *is* blocked.